# SVN: two branches with differenct configuration

Tags: svn

I have a project in SVN and i want to create two branches. But the only thing that differs is the configuration file (app.config). Is it possible that when i edit the trunk, the changes are automatically added to the two branches?

Answer (score 2):

**Short and easy answer**

No

**Longer answer**

Still "No", but "you can perform additional actions and get 3 operaitons -> 3 commits".

Explanation: you can't change 3 independent targets by changing only one, but you can distribute changeover repository. In order to do it, you can after commit to trunk merge trunk into each branch (one branch - one merge). In order to merge from trunk to branch you have to have clean Working Copy on each target branch and (by hand or in post-commit hook) after commit to trunk `svn merge ^/trunk WC-OF-BRANCH & commit -m "Merge trunk" WC-OF-BRANCH` for each branch

---

**Alternative solution**

If your branches differ only in one (rarely changed???) file, you can eliminate branches totally - store template of app.config in repository andmove task of preparing real config onto Builder|Deployer script (it can be some sed, or patching template by patch1|patch2, which you also store in repository)

Comment: +1: I was going to give the same answer: This is something you're better off doing in your _build step_. You can even have multiple configuration files, and simply copy the correct one to the name `app.config` as part of the build process.